# Find a ratio of triangle's height segment

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, ratio

Given a right angle triangle `ABC` (C = 90) and a median `AM`. `CD` is the height of the triangle and it intersects median in point `K`. What is the `CK / KD` ratio?

Answer (score 2):

Let $AC=b$, $BC=a$ and $N$ be placed on $DB$ such that $MN\perp AB.$

Thus, $$MN=\frac{1}{2}CD,$$
$$AD=\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$ and
$$BD=\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$
Id est, $$\frac{KD}{MN}=\frac{AD}{AN}=\frac{\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}{\frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\frac{a^2}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}}=\frac{2b^2}{a^2+2b^2}.$$
Thus, $$\frac{KD}{CD}=\frac{b^2}{a^2+2b^2}$$ or
$$\frac{CD}{KD}=\frac{a^2+2b^2}{b^2}$$ or
$$1+\frac{CK}{KD}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{b^2}+1,$$ which gives
$$CK:KD=(a^2+b^2):b^2.$$
We see that the needed ratio depends on the ratio $a:b$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but could you explain the part where you come up with KD to MN ratio, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have a different answer

$$ \frac{CK}{KD} = \frac{a-b}{b} $$

so I want to clarify: how did you conclude that

$$ MN = \frac{b^2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} + \frac{a^2}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

I have `MN` equals to $ \frac{ab}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$